# Periodic tasks in celery from different modules

Tags: python, celery

I have main file for working with celery `app.py`.
Besides other info in the file I have the following:

```
app = Celery(__name__, include=['tasks.parsers', 'tasks.statistics'])
```

My file `tasks.parsers` includes:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=23, minute=0),
        task_parsers()
    )
```

My file `tasks.statistics` includes:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=2, minute=0),
        task_statistics()  
    )
```

My main goal is using the celery, to include periodic tasks from different python modules. In provided example, is that a correct way to do so? Would not they override each other? Should not be the `setup_periodic_tasks` method included only once?

Comment: Who might come here with a similar question - check my git example of celery periodic tasks structure https://github.com/trthhrtz/celery_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **TLDR**: Use unique names for your receivers.

Currently registering receivers that way can mess with one's mind.

Now, a function redefined with the same name and the same block may be expected to produce the different identity each time. This is not so as you will see. Python sometimes reuses the same memory address for the redefined function.

```
>>> def foo(): print('bar')
...
>>> print(id(foo))
4307375360

>>> def foo(): print('bar')
...
>>> print(id(foo))
4307375240

>>> def foo(): print('bar')
...
>>> print(id(foo))
4307375360
```

So what really is happening when you connect your receiver this way.
You may have 2 registered receiver for the signal or just one (last registered receiver wins) depending on whether `id` returns the same identity or not ([Learn more about how Celery registers a receiver and computes a lookup key](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.1.0/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py#L159).)

`@app.on_after_configure.connect` decorator helps you register a receiver after celery is configured. The name of the receiver isn't necessarily important as much as maintaining the signature for the receiver is.